# Firebase: allow to read collection by admins and specific records by users

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a structure like this:

```
{ "users": {
  {
    "uid1" : {
      "admin" : true,
      "email" : "admin@app.com",
      "name" : "Admin User"
    },
    "uid2" : {
      "email" : "user1@app.com",
      "name" : "User 1"
    },
    "uid3" : {
      "email" : "user2@app.com",
      "name" : "User 2"
    }
  }
}
```

I have the following rules, which allow an admin or the user himself to read one user's data and work as expected:

```
{
  "users": {
    ".read": true,

    "$uid": {
      // data is the user's or user is admin
      ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('admin').val() == true || auth.uid == $uid",
    }
  }
}
```

**What do I need to do to, in addition to what the rules already allow, have the admin users be able to list all users in the collection?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Firebase, once you grant a permission, you cannot revoke it a further down the tree. So the `".read": true` under `users` grants read permissions to all users.

You need to change the rule under `users` so that it's `true` only for admins. Doing so will also allow admins to list users (and should also see the other rule effect the behaviour you expect):

```
{
  "users": {
    ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('admin').val() === true",
    "$uid": {
      ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('admin').val() === true || auth.uid === $uid",
    }
  }
}
```

This can be simplified - as mentioned in the comments - because the rule under `users` cascades down and doesn't need to be repeated:

```
{
  "users": {
    ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('admin').val() === true",
    "$uid": {
      ".read": "auth.uid === $uid"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Since the read permission of admins already cascades down, you don't need to repeat the admin permission under `$uid`. That rule can just be `".read": "auth.uid === $uid"`

Comment: Nice! Looks like I've misinterpreted the documentation. Works fine, thanks!